# While loop won't terminate

Tags: python, sorting, while-loop

Learning Python.  This task is to allow the user to enter numbers as long as the number isn't -99.  If the sentinel -99 is entered, the user will no longer be able to enter numbers, and the largest and smallest numbers that have already been entered will be displayed.  When I enter the number -99, however, the loop continues to ask for new numbers.

```
#main module
def main():

    #Instructions for user
    print ("This program will allow the user to enter several numbers, 
    positive ")
    print ("or negative, and sort the largest and smallest numbers from 
    them.")

    #First number entered by user
    inputNum = input ("Enter a number other than -99 to be sorted: ")


    #variables
    number = inputNum
    small=number
    large=number

    #while loop for getting/sorting numbers
    while number != -99:
        if number < small:
            small = number
        elif number > large:
            large = number
        inputNum = input("Enter a number other than -99 to be sorted: ")


    lgSm()


#Module for displaying large and small numbers
def lgSm():
    print ("The largest number you entered is: ", large)
    print ("The smallest number you entered is: ", small)


main()
```

Edit:

Solved.  I forgot to add the variables inside the ()...I'm not sure what these are called, but I do understood their function.  Are they called placeholder variables?

```
#main module
def main():

    #Instructions for user
    print ("This program will allow the user to enter several numbers, positive ")
    print ("or negative, and sort the largest and smallest numbers from them.")

    #First number entered by user
    inputNum = int (input ("Enter a number other than -99 to be sorted: "))


    #variables
    number=inputNum
    small=number
    large=number


    while number != -99:
        if number < small:
            small = number
        elif number > large:
            large = number
        inputNum = int (input("Enter a number other than -99 to be sorted: "))
        number = inputNum

    lgSm(large, small)


#Module for displaying large and small numbers
def lgSm(lg, sm):
    print ("The largest number you entered is: ", lg)
    print ("The smallest number you entered is: ", sm)
```

main()

Comment: you are saying while number...  The value of number is not changing

Comment: I added a line as shown below but it didn't help :(

Comment: You need to do something with input. Maybe you can change it to an int somehow.  Get to work figuring out how to do that

Comment: @RSon1234 ended up missing variables in the module.  thanks for the hint

Comment: Cool.  good luck

Comment: If you're still around...what are those called?  I added lg,sm in the module and used large, small when i called the module in main.  Placeholder variables?

Comment: Those are parameters. When you called it you passed the arguments

Comment: Go check out some things like parameters vs arguments.  Also understand local variables.  Why doesn't the lgsm function just know what large and small is and so on.  That will help you out

Answer (score 1):

Modify your while loop to update number variable; the value of number is not changing inside the loop

```
while number != -99:
    if number < small:
        small = number
    elif number > large:
        large = number
    inputNum = int(input("Enter a number other than -99 to be sorted: "))
    number = inputNum ## this line in particular
```

Comment: Let me predict the next comment: "This still doesn't work!"  HINT: `intput` returns a `str` in Python 3.